# How to share variables between stages in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have following pipeline (content simplified, but the structure is exact):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
                    my_var = ""
                }
    stages {
        stage('Stage_parallel'){
            parallel{
                stage('Stage_1') {
                    steps {
                        ...
                    }
                }
                stage('Stage_2'){
                    steps {
                        withCredentials([usernamePassword(<LOGIN>, <PASS>)])
                        {
                            sh'''
                                  ...
                                  var_1 = "/path/to/folder"
                                  var_2 = "file_name"
                                  my_var = "${var_1}/${var_2}"
                                  echo ${my_var} ### returns correct value
                            '''
                        }}}}}
        stage('Stage_3'){
            steps {
                sh 'echo ${my_var}' ### returns ""
            }}}}
```

So I tried to declare global variable, update it in `Stage_2` and use in `Stage_3`. However, it returns correct value only in `Stage_2` `sh` block, but not outside... I also tried to

- define variable outside the `pipeline` block like `def my_var`
- define it in `Stage_2` as `env.my_var = "${var_1}/${var_2}"` and use in `Stage_3` as `${env.my_var}`

but none of approaches allows to get `my_var` value from `Stage_2`... So how should I fix the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins passes environment variables to scripts "by value", not "by reference", conceptually speaking. If you want to persist any state between `sh` steps (doesn't matter inside the same stage or different stages) you have two options:

1. Pass the state information back to Jenkins (serialize to stdout and capture it in Jenkins), but you sacrifice declarative purity
2. Save it in some file in the workspace, which is not such a good idea generally speaking, but acceptable in very simple cases

Pick your poison.

Comment: How about not environment environments? Is there a Jenkins built-in functionality to share string values between stages?

Comment: Of course! Again, two options - not declaring a variable (skip `def`) or declaring it before the pipeline statement. If you want to share it between stages and methods (in a scripted pipeline) then you can declare it with `@Field` annotation.

Comment: Only writing into/reading from text file option worked for me. At least something)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you define "my_var" in the environment, but in your Step 2 as shown, you create a local variable my_var, there is a difference between env.my_var and my_var.

To access you environment my_var, you will need to access it in your stages via:

```bash
env.my_var="something you want to do"
```

Comment: and how should I use it correctly? `${env.my_var}`?